# How do I get Eevee Mantaflow fire to not look pixelated?

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine, mantaflow

I know this type of question has been asked a lot, but no one else's solution works for me. I'm using Blender 3.0, I would be willing to update but not to go to an older version because I need this to be a part of another project that I've already made a lot of progress into and I don't want to lose functionality in it.

I also can't use Cycles. Even if my computer could handle it, which it can't, that aformentioned project is based in Eevee very heavily.

Fyi I need this fire to be animated so please bear in mind that while I'm rendering as a still image for sampling, it will be animated.

So here's my shader:

[image]

I've tried many other things, including using blackbody. This is the best I can get out of it.

Rendered version:
[image]

As you can see... Very blurry and pixelated.

Here's my render settings, I've messed around a lot with the clip settings and such and this is the best I could get:

[image]

And here's the actual domain settings, higher resolution doesn't really make any difference and my computer can't really handle it reasonably, noise helps a bit but doesn't really solve it:

[image]

I'm currently waiting for the .blend to process on blend-exchange and will include it once that's done if no one's been able to answer by then.

Edit: [image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: maybe your problem is not that it is pixellated but on the contrary that the details are too small? Try to lower down the Vorticity and increase the Noise Scale? Or please share your file

Comment: @moonboots I got the link to the .blend added now

Comment: I don't know smoke with particle system, I hope someone will help

Comment: @moonboots It has the same issue without the particle system